# How do I prevent duplicates on my Cart section

Tags: reactjs, function, duplicates

There is a function "addToCart" that I'm using to show the content of a cart, but i'm getting duplicates.

How can I prevent this.

```
    function addToCart (product, count) {

    const newCart = cart.map((item) => item);
    const newItemInCart = { count, ...product };
    newCart.push(newItemInCart);
    setCart(newCart);

    }
```

Idk how to start doing it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check if the product already exists in the cart before adding it. If the product already exists, you can update its count instead of adding a new entry.

```
function addToCart(product, count) {
  // Check if the product already exists in the cart
  const existingItemIndex = cart.findIndex(
    (item) => item.id === product.id
  );

  if (existingItemIndex !== -1) {
    // Product already exists in the cart, update the count
    const newCart = cart.map((item, index) => {
      if (index === existingItemIndex) {
        return {
          ...item,
          count: item.count + count,
        };
      } else {
        return item;
      }
    });

    setCart(newCart);
  } else {
    // Product doesn't exist in the cart, add it as a new item
    const newItemInCart = { count, ...product };
    const newCart = [...cart, newItemInCart];
    setCart(newCart);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I have to keep on studying.

Answer (score 0):

To prevent duplicates in your cart, you need to check if the product already exists in the cart before adding it. If it exists, you can simply increase the count of that product, otherwise, you add the product as a new item. Here's how you can do it:

```html
function addToCart(product: ProductType, count: number): void {
  const existingProductIndex = cart.findIndex((item) => item.id === product.id);

  if (existingProductIndex >= 0) {
    const newCart = [...cart];
    newCart[existingProductIndex].count += count;
    setCart(newCart);
  } else {
    const newItemInCart = { count, ...product };
    setCart((prevCart) => [...prevCart, newItemInCart]);
  }
}
```